# How to convert to a multi-class classification model?

Tags: google-cloud-ml, multilabel-classification

I am trying to implement multi-class classification using the [cloud samples github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers).It was a classification model and i have to alter the code.I found some suggestion to change the final layer and loss from softmax to sigmoid.Also I have to change labels to one hot encoding.Could someone help in changing labels to one hot encoding 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to do multi-label classification? In multi-class, the semantics are roughly, "One of these class is the label, although each label has some degree of uncertainty to it (you can think of each label being assigned a probability such that the probabilities sum to one)". Vs. Multi-label which is: "Each label independently has some probability of being present; they probabilities do not some to one"?

Comment: It is multi-label classifcation

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-image-classification-with-inception-net-cbb2ee538e30

The technique used in that article looks something like this:

```
ground_truth = np.zeros(class_count, dtype=np.float32)
ground_truth[label_index] = 1.0
```

This may not scale well for a very large number of classes (10s of thousands). To scale to higher numbers of classes, you need the equivalent of `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` for sigmoid, which doesn't seem to exist.